# Boot Camp fails to create a Windows partition because it can't move files

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp, defragment

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) on a mac with a 320 GB drive, 167GB free space, and I can't get Boot Camp running. The wizard starts creating the Windows partition, but fails with a message claiming it cannot move some files. The message suggests to back up my hard disk, reformat it, restore my files, and re-run Boot Camp wizard.

The problem is: Though I do have backups (Time Machine), I don't feel like formatting my hard disk right now :-)

I found a thread in some forum discussing this problem. The suggestion was to defragment my volume with iDefrag, and lots of people claimed that solved the issue. So I went ahead and got iDefrag 1.7.1, created a bootable DVD and chose the "compact" setting recommended before partitioning - but still no luck with Boot Camp! So how do I get this working?

Fun note: last year, I briefly set up Boot Camp with 10.5, and it worked perfectly. Probably I did not use that much hard disk space back then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had your exact problem. To solve it I used TechTool Pro's bootable DVD to perform free space consolidation (they call it volume optimization).

Answer (score 2):

iDefrag fixed this for me - you need to do a full defrag, not just a compact.
Compact just removes the spaces between the files - (directory fragmentation) you want to defrag the files too.

Cloning the drive and format/ re-install will do it, too but it's a lot of work as you say in your question.

Might be worth checking there aren't any problems with the drive by repairing in Disk Utility too before the defrag.

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours of tinkering and not wanting to attempt defragmenting due to time limitations, I booted into safe mode (hold Shift while booting) - finally Bootcamp Assistant worked!

Answer (score 0):

If defragmenting didn't work you're only option is to format. I've ran into this issue numerous times and a format was the only way to get it to work. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Couldn't partition the HD because "some files could not be moved".

**I booted in safe mode. ( do this by rebooting and holding down the shift key after you here the chime)

**The solution that worked for me was repairing disk partition with disk utility on mac in safe mode. (Open disk utility and Under utilities in your applications folder.)

**open disk utilities in safe mode and verify and repair disk partitions

**once its done, reboot normal and try to install again and it should work.

now windows runs so smooth, almost smoother on a mac than a PC. I used windows 7, free download through the college. Roll Tide! Hope it helps! This is free instead of using iDefrag.